# WheelNav.js SVG RTL Arabic Text Wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, svg, wheelnav.js

I have some text written in Arabic and I'm having a little bit of an issue wrapping it in a wheelnav.js navigation item, here's a jsFiddle:

[WheelNav.js Arabic Text Wrapping Problem jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03s13msw/)

I've been thinking of injecting an SVG **foreignobject** that can hopefully take care of the problem, I have an idea how to do it but not exactly in which part of wheelnav.js to do it, here's a sample code from mozilla dev:

```
<svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <desc>This example uses the 'switch' element to provide a 
        fallback graphical representation of a paragraph, if 
        XHTML is not supported.</desc>

  <switch>


    <foreignObject width="100" height="50"
                   requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <!-- XHTML content goes here -->
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>

    <text font-size="10" font-family="Verdana">
      <tspan x="10" y="10">Here is a paragraph that</tspan>
      <tspan x="10" y="20">requires word wrap.</tspan>
    </text>
  </switch>
 </svg>
```

I appreciate any help I can get or even alternative solutions.

Comment: You've used line break (\n) in some of those lines. Is there a reason you can't just use that?

Comment: line breaks \n works for English words just fine, however when its Arabic the words are not arranged properly, sometimes the start of a paragraph begins at the bottom line and ends at the top with broken ends, I've written an algorithm to reverse the entire paragraph and it did logically reverse it however the result was almost the same, for example this sentence in arabic:

مرحبا بالعالم الجديد

is from right to left, if I add line breaks to it as I have done, it should look from this:

مرحبا\nبالعالم\nالجديد

to this http://imgur.com/a/k0Ie3

Comment: So the text is dynamic then? You don't know beforehand what it is going to be?

Comment: Precisely, the text is fetched from the database and can be different, meaning I cannot use images/icons as text replacement....or can I?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify wheelnav.js for this here:

```
//Title defined by path
if (wheelnavTitle().isPathTitle(this.title)) {
    this.navTitle = this.wheelnav.raphael.path(currentTitle.path);
}
//Title defined by image
else if (wheelnavTitle().isImageTitle(this.title)) {
    this.navTitle = this.wheelnav.raphael.image(currentTitle.src, sliceInitPath.titlePosX - (this.titleWidth / 2), sliceInitPath.titlePosY - (this.titleHeight / 2), this.titleWidth, this.titleHeight);
}
//Title defined by text
else {
    this.navTitle = this.wheelnav.raphael.text(sliceInitPath.titlePosX, sliceInitPath.titlePosY, currentTitle.title);
}
```

You must add an other else branch for foreignobject.

You can find the source [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.0/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L961).

I've found a [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/neyric/609717) which would be useful.

Comment: I've went through these before, I tried to dynamically create a foreign object and add it to the nav title however I think its wrong to do it that way, what I tried next is modifying raphael.js (uncompressed source) R._engine.text = function (svg, x, y, text) by appending the foreign object to the svg canvas, it worked somewhat and now displays the Arabic wrapped text correctly however it seems to be positioned in absolute mode, it won't rotate with the wheel at all, any ideas from there?

Comment: Did you add your new object to the [navItem](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.0/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L1000) set?